# Set the react CSS loader in locally, but I get an error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

```
test: cssRegex,
exclude: cssModuleRegex,
use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
}),
```

And the error is:

> ./src/index.css
>   (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been
>   initialised using an options object that does not match the API
>   schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:    object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?,
>   importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }

Answer (score 7):

You're using a `css-loader` 3.0.x [that has moved `localIdentName` into the `modules` object](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2019-06-11).

Try

```
modules: {
  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
},
```

instead of

```
modules: true,
```